# How to scan if a channel is dmchannel as a response by the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I was Making a bot like asking questions from the user and I encountered the following problem , I installed all the required libraries and they work

```
@client.command()
async def partner(ctx):
  def check(m):
    if m.channel == discord.channel.DMChannel and m.author == ctx.author:
      return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == discord.DMChannel
  x = ["hello","hi"]
  for i in x:
    msg.content=msg.content.lower()
    await  discord.DMChannel.send(ctx.author,i)
    try:
      msg = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await discord.DMChannel.send(ctx.author,"Please dont take that long for your answer, be quicker next time")
      return
    else:
      if msg.content =="cancel":
        await discord.DMChannel.send(ctx.author,"Ok Cancelling partnership, you can still re-apply")
       return
    answers.append(msg.content)
```

But the  problem is that I can't actually get the output I want also if you see any mistake in the indents of my code , I am doing on mobile and for that reason , and. I check all the things on internet , but none of them helped me ,I'm thankful for any help you can give

After Edit:
The Answer below is correct and if you all want to use it then do this

```py
  def check(m):
    if m.author == ctx.author and isinstance(m.channel,discord.DMChannel):
      return m.author == ctx.author
```

and it works. Thank you so much for sharing the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check using the channel like this

```py
if isinstance(channel, discord.DMChannel):
```

Also when sending a dm to the user use

```py
await ctx.author.send("Test")
```

Comment: Well then what should i return when the condition is true , to the check one please tell me

Comment: When the condition is `True` then the channel is a DM do what you want with it.

Comment: Thank you very much , solved my problem and it works fine